# What is the meaning of Lagrange Multiplier in this formula?

Tags: notation, matrix-calculus

Consider $$F = L'VL + (L' X − K' )\Phi$$

$L$, $V$ and $K$ are matrices.
$F$: function notation

$\Phi$: Lagrange Multiplier, imposes the restriction $L' X = K'$

What does Lagrange Multiplier mean in this formula?

Page 48:
http://www.aps.uoguelph.ca/~lrs/ABModels/DATA/EuropeNotes.pdf

Comment: A Lagrange multipler method allows you to optimise a functional subject to some constraint by building in the constraint into the optimisation model. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Example_1 for an example.

Comment: Then why the differentiate of the function with respect to $\phi$ was calculated? Should we use $\phi$ for Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: @user1436187 $\Phi$ is the lagrange multiplier; you said that yourself. You differentiate it to find local minima or maxima (which happens when the derivative is zero).